# Chrome - stretch background image without keeping ratio

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have the following code:

```css
.container {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1142760/static/svg/triangle.svg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

I expect the background image of the `div` to be stretched to the full `width` and `height` of said `div`.

Firefox behaves as expected:

[image: the arrow is nicely stretched to the full width and height of the container, distorting the original image's aspect ratio]

But Chrome appears to have a bug that makes it interpret `background-size` differently:

[image]

You can see the live result in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0j5tejw/1/)

Re-creating the background image would not be a solution, as the `div` in question is of variable `height`.

Is there a work-around for this Chrome bug?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize svg image as background in chrome browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491654/resize-svg-image-as-background-in-chrome-browser)

Comment: Check what @Brewal posted or do not use SVG.

Comment: As a side note, a triangle could be [easily made](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) with pure css.

Comment: Also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334095/background-size100-100-doesnt-work-properly-in-chrome

Comment: @Brewal I know about the triangle-css trick, but in some browsers it's not anti-aliased and doesn't look perfect

Comment: Yes, it turns out to be a duplicate question. I think that [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17492515/1467284) looks most elegant

Comment: For what I can remember, you can rotate it 360° to prevent aliasing in most cases

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone will find this post and not find the right answer.
I found out that in my case, i had to add an attribute to my svg File:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" ...
```

Comment: I think this should be the right answer. SVG behaves differently. Note that if the `viewBox` attribute is not provided, then `preserveAspectRatio` is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe not the best solution, but at least it works fine for me in Chrome.
But you have to set the height (transform-scale) of the inner div with JQuery, according to your browser on load. Not really nice, but it works.
Also watch out for the -webkit-background-size.

As you can see, a lot of problems.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div id="picture"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:1rem;
    height:2rem;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#picture {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: 
    url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1142760/static/svg/triangle.svg);
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y0j5tejw/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for your code, it will definitely resolve your query.

```
.container{

    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1142760/static/svg/triangle.svg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    float: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 5%;
height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it help you. I have edited only some part of your code.ok

Comment: @KubaOrlik what is the problem now.. please let me know and It is working properly ..