# css background image fit to div

Tags: css, image, html, background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stretch and Scale a CSS image Background - With CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only)

I want to set div background image div(width: 1000, min-height: 710) and the image size is 753 x 308
whan I trying to set it image is not getting fit to the div size what should i do?

```
.Invitation {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('../images/form.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 710px;
    margin-left: 43px;
}
```

The div class is

```
.content {  
   clear:both;  
   width:1000px;    
   background:#e7e8e9;
   background-image:url('../images/content.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:left top;
   min-height:710px;
}
```

and the code is

```
<div class="content"><div class="Invitation">form goes here....</div></div>
```

Comment: Are you tring to scale the background-image to fit (proportionally) or stretch (distort) to the DIV?

Comment: the image should cover the div.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  img.adjusted {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .Invitation {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 710px;
    margin-left: 43px;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Invitation">
  This is an example
  <img src="http://files.myopera.com/arshamr/albums/612249/Nature%20(3).jpg" alt="" class="adjusted">
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note that negative zindex may hide the element in some versions of Firefox due to a bug where the element is rendered below the document. It may be safe by now, I've not tested with 3.6 nor the newer versions.

Comment: Well, at least according to the standard, there's no limit to z-index, either value positive or negative

Comment: You're right. CSS 2.0 doesn't specify a limit and 2.1 specify that negative values are allowed, but old versions of FF have this bug.

Comment: Its a background image.How this code be possible?

Comment: Yes, try it! It's an image underlying that is achieved through the attribute z-index, furthermore is positioned at the top and that makes it seem like a background...

Comment: To avoid possible css hack due to the bug of FF, could be used a conditional to modify the z-index value to positive and add "display: none" to image element. Moreover, I think it you could also play with positive values for z-index, putting "This is an example" or any content within a div element with relative position and a z-index value greather than the of image.