# CSS vertical stretch to background

Tags: css

I cannot seem to get my background image to stretch vertically (with CSS) and have not been able to get it.. What's the best way to do this without using a jquery plugin?

http://realestateunusual.com/

Currently have

```
div#whitewrap {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: FYI, in the future, please be sure to look at similar questions which already exist here - such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only?rq=1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the question is unclear, I assume you want the houses to appear at the bottom of the page?

The `body` does not fill the screen unless it has to. Thus, your `whitewrap` div only fills 100% of the `body`.

Either you need to set the body height to 100% too (although this is slightly hacky) or set the background of the `body` to the image. This will then have the background image at the bottom of the screen (despite the body not being the full height - confusing right?).

Your HTML is hard to inspect however, due (I assume) to the software you used to create it adding in more `div`s than I thought possible!

**EDIT:** after closer inspection, it looks as if you need to set the `background-position` attribute to force the image to the bottom. Then, you can set the `background-color` to be the same as the colour of the sky at the top of the image. This should create the effect you desire without having to actually stretch & distort your image.

Comment: The crazy HTML is from the live chat plugin..Setting body to 100% does not seem to do it..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this completely using CSS: using the background-size attribute.

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/250/150);
    background-size: 100%;
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5TSVP/.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Media Queries in your CSS and store different resolution images for major platforms.  The images can then resize between with browser.

Media Queries:  http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

```
@media (min-width:800px) { background-image: url(bg-800.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1024px) { background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1280px) { background-image: url(bg-1280.jpg) }
```

CSS for img tag to let it resize:

```
img { max-width:100%; }
```