# Stretch a background image in CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stretch and Scale a CSS image Background - With CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only)

A beginner question:
This might be a basic question and i could be missing some basic idea. I have seen This question but i think that is not near to my problem. I want to stretch my Background image in CSS. Here is my CSS code
**CSS:**

```
.BackgroundColor
{
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image: url('Content/Tulips.jpg');//this image i want to stretch
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

and here is my HTML code 
**HTML:**

```
<div class="BackgroundColor">
    <div class="outerMost">
    <div class="heading" id="loginheading">
      Show Login  
    </div>
    <div class="MainSect">
        <div class="Label">
        <asp:Label ID="usernameLabel" runat="server" Text="UserName" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="textboxes" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text="Password" CssClass="Label" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="textboxes"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Login"  
            BackColor="#00CCFF" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="loginButton" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth" CssClass="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="CalenderTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="textboxes"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div id="tabSection">
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#basicInfo">Basic info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SavingAccount">Depositer</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="basicInfo">
        Basic Info will be mentioned here and bla bla bla
        </div>
        <div id="Products">
        Products and other releases should be mentioned here

        </div>
        <div id="SavingAccount">
        Information about saving account should be mentioned here and bla bla bla
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

So i want to set background image on the page.Ignore the inner code. Kindly help me stretching the image because my `Style builder` does not show any property regarding stretching the image. The above link i mentioned is stretching the image in Html but i want to do it in CSS.
**EDIT:**
And please tell me how to include CSS3 in visual studio because my CSS editor shows upto CSS2.1
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for the sake that others would find it if they get the same problem. Because some part of my question was not answered by SO users. I have searched it and found the answer so i am answering that part
 
this is the link where anyone can download the CSS3 intellisense schema.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210

After installing it Visual Studio will show CSS3 in CSS editor u can select it from there. and then Use the property

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
is more beautiful?

Answer (score 8):

In CSS3 you can simply use `background-size: cover` documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/).

> **cover**: Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio
>   (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height
>   can completely cover the background positioning area.

Otherwise see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208392/944681).

Comment: You made my day!

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: yes i wanted to do this but compiler intellicense of compiler does not show. I think thats a property of CSS3 but i am not able to include CSS3 in project because i am working on it for the first time

Answer (score 3):

You could use background-size:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Here is a demo of it:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size2

```
background-size:100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  background: url(yourimage.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

for stretching image at background image should be 100%"
in your css us put px change it to % 
also add background size = 100%
your css become

```
.BackgroundColor
{
background-position: center center;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-image: url('Content/Tulips.jpg');//this image i want to stretch
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would use a width and height of 100%.