# Vertically stretch background image

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to stretch a background image vertically. I am using CSS3 with 3 images in the following way:

```
background-image: url("left.png"), url("right.png"), url("center.png")
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x
background-position: top left, top right, top
```

Now I want to stretch these images vertically to that they extend all the way to the bottom. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. You can resize (stretch/squish) `<img>` tags, though: the solution may involve putting an `<img>` in the background, positioned absolutely and such.

Comment: This might be a good place to look: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only

Comment: Also, pretty sure you're not supposed to put quotes around your `url`s like that.

Answer (score 53):

I'm late to the party here, but this is what worked for me:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

This will fit the image vertically and let the width do whatever it needs to do (i think it repeats by default). You can also set:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

for it to not repeat the image in the horizontal direction.

Comment: I also needed to set `background-position: center;`

Comment: `background-size: cover;` is worth exploring

Answer (score 32):

Try:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

first `100%` is for the width and the second for the height. In your case you need the second set to `100%`

Comment: How do I just set the height to 100%? If I do background-size: 100%, it sets both width and height to a 100%.

Comment: This was pretty handy.  In my case, I set "background-size: 960px 100%;" to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing up this question. Below is what worked for me

```
background-size: cover;
background-color: #a8dadc;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
```