# How to center the browser over an image wider than the site

Tags: javascript, css

My site is 900px wide.  I have an image I'd like to run wider, 1300px, but still be centered over the page.  Currently, when I open the page in a browser, i am centered on the left side of the image. I can ctrl+mouse wheel to zoom out and have it be closer to what my goal is.  But I don't want site viewers to have to do this.  How can I fix this reasonably easily?

Comment: Maybe this is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best bet is to go with a bit of JavaScript that transforms the image from a `<img>` tag into a background image:

```
<div class="wide-image"><img src="..."></div>
```

JavaScript using jQuery (but you can easily do this without it / with some other tool):

```
​​$(function() {
    $('.wide-image').each(function() {
        var $div = $(this),
            $img = $div.find('img:first');

        // Transform normal image into background image
        $div.css('background', 'url(' + $img.attr('src') + ') no-repeat center center');

        // Adjust the <div>s height to fit the image's height
        $div.height($img.height());        

        // Hide the original image
        $img.hide();
    });
});​
```

​
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NBKsm/

Answer (score 0):

You mean center a background-image?

`background-position: center 0`

That should work since it can accept center for a value: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
margin : 0px auto;
```

use this css code in which div's class where your img is there.