# Filling a div with an image (ignoring proportions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to fill a parent `<div>` with an image, while completely ignoring proportions.  I know that it will look ugly at certain dimensions, I just want to see if it's possible at this point.  As you can see, the image is scaling, rather than stretching to my demands (Chrome):  http://jsfiddle.net/qdzaw/61/

Unfortunately, all I can find online is how to do this while maintaining proportions :/

```
<img class="someimage" src="imgsrc" />

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".someimage").height($(".someimage").parent().height());     
    $(".someimage").width($(".someimage").parent().width());  
});
```

Comment: It works fine in firefox, the div is completely filled by the image.

Comment: If your container has defined width and height, setting `$(".someimage").css({ width: '100%', height: '100%' });` should do it http://jsfiddle.net/qdzaw/62/

Comment: If IE support isn't an issue `background-size:contain` will do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

i think i find your answer in this post: [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only#answer-1208392)

use a parent div element and this stylesheet:

```
div {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}

img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
   position:relative;
}
div img {
   position:absolute; 
   top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```