# Background images that fill window?

Tags: css

I have a background image and I want to fill the entire background of my site. I use:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

The image is 2000px x 2000px. The problem is, when the browser window is larger than 2000px you can see a white background. Is there a way to get the image to strech if the browser window is large than the image?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only?rq=1

Comment: What element are you using that CSS on?

Answer (score 1):

First of all avoid using such large images as background if you are just using it for background .  You can do it like this  dont put everything to cover .Just in style tag put these two   and you will get it  .

```
background-image:url('your image');
background-size: cover;
```

Quality of image may be disturbed if it expands too much  but this works  .

Comment: This doesn't work. I've made my image smaller but it doesnt fill the screen now.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using this:

```
background: url(../img/url.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` seems to work for me both ways -- both shrinking an image to fill if it's larger than the element, or stretching the image to fill if it's smaller. Here's an example of a small image stretching to fill a larger div: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/Q7STG/