# Easiest way to accomplish a large image background stretching based on browser width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you go to [www.joinbunch.com](http://www.joinbunch.com) and resize the browser, you can see that the background image scales very nicely when resized.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean with "rotates"? I can only see it resized when I shinrk the window.

Comment: My bad, scale is what I meant, not rotate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with css `background-size cover`.  This will scale an image so it will cover the entire area.

```
 #myelement {
     background: url(myback.png) cover;
 }
```

full syntax:

```
 #myelement {
     background-image:url(myback.png);
     background-size:cover;
 }
```

Comment: This is the way that the site provided is doing it. They have a selector of `.bg-wrapper #bg0, .bg-wrapper #bg1` and it's applying `width:100%;height:100%;background-size:cover;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:none;z-index:0;overflow:hidden;background-position:center center;`

Answer (score 1):

The background image of the `<div>` containing the image must have the attribute `width` to a `100%`... or some other percentage.

To explain it a little bit more:

Check this Link
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

***Via CSS3***

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

***"USUAL" way***

**HTML markup**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS markup**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

They also provide a demo:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-2.php

I recommend that page, it has a lot of tricks for css.

Hope it helps!