# Can you add a background image in html?

Tags: html, css, background

Is it possible to to add a background image in the html?

here is my fiddle i need it on the "container div"

I also need the background to stretch across the canvas can  i do this in the css??

http://jsfiddle.net/7Gacp/3/

```
<div id="profile-container">
    <div id="fixed-header"></div>
    <div class="container" style="background: url("../../img/followers/followers-tabs.png") no-repeat 0 0px;"></div>
    <div class="sticky-header">This needs to be fixed when hits top of screen</div>
    <div class="img">needs to be smooth</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only

Comment: Fix your quotes: `"background: url("../../img/followers/followers-tabs.png") no-repeat 0 0px;"` to `"background: url('../../img/followers/followers-tabs.png') no-repeat 0 0px;"`

Comment: could you add fiddle please?

Comment: C'mon, this is absolutly basic for every developer, and beside that it's just a 10sec google search.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the double quotes and use single quotes instead like this

```
"background: url('../../img/followers/followers-tabs.png')
```

Comment: could you add fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

`background-image:url('image path');` 
put this block of code in ur css and get the background image set.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
 height:300px;
 width:100%;
 background-image: url("Put your image link here.");
}
```

Would work for inline styling:

```
<div class="container" style="background: url('Put your image link here.') no-repeat 0 0px;"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gacp/12/)

Comment: I need to do inline  css for programming reasons.

Comment: Sorry! I also forgot to save the modified fiddle. A previous answer would work as well, you just need to change the double quotes to single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove qoutes from the url

```
<div class="container" style="background: url(../../img/followers/followers-tabs.png) no-repeat 0 0px;"></div>
```

You could use `'` but `url` in CSS background doesn't need them at all.

Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gacp/10/.

To spread the background you can use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gacp/11/.