# Fit website background image to screen size

Tags: html, css, background, size, responsive

I'm just starting on a website and I already encounter a small problem where I can't find a specific solution to.

I wanted to make my website background fit any screen size in width, height does not matter.

This is the link to my image:

```
    ../IMAGES/background.jpg
```

EDIT

I have no idea what's wrong, but for some reason the body doesn't even want to get the background image. It just displays a plain white background.

```
body
{background-image:url(../IMAGES/background.jpg);}
```

Comment: There are so many question like yours. Please use the search function! And the image path is your local path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

you can  do this with this plugin http://dev.andreaseberhard.de/jquery/superbgimage/

or

```
   background-image:url(../IMAGES/background.jpg);

   background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
```

with no need the prefixes of browsers. it's all ready suporterd in both of browsers

Comment: This solution doesn't work in case of mobile screens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852187/background-image-is-not-occupying-full-screen-height-on-mobile

Answer (score 27):

Try this ,

```
 background: url(../IMAGES/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

For more information , follow this [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) !!

Comment: It's a little bit old thread, but It actually worked good for me, but be sure to place this CSS in the html {} and NOT in the body {}.

Comment: This is perfect for all kinds of devices. Keeping image center performs the magic

Answer (score 21):

You can try with

```
.appBackground {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(".../img/background.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100vh;
}
```

works for me :)

Comment: This one is the only correct solution. The key to success is "100vh".

Comment: finally an answer that doesn't just say "use background-size: cover", this works.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I hope it will help:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url('background.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
body{
    background-image: url(".../img/background.jpg");
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
background: url(../IMAGES/background.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: auto auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

.. I found the above solutions didn't work for me (on current versions of firefox and safari at least).

In my case I'm actually trying to do it with an img tag, not background-image, though it should also work for background-image if you use z-height:

```
<img  src='$url' style='position:absolute; top,left:0px; width,max-height:100%; border:0;' >
```

This scales the image to be 'fullscreen' (probably breaking the aspect ratio) which was what I wanted to do but had a hard-time finding.

It may also work for background-image though I gave up on trying that kind of solution after cover/contain didn't work for me.

I found contain behaviour didn't seem to match the documentation I could find anywhere - I understood the documentation to say contain should make the largest dimension get contained within the screen (maintained aspect).  I found contain always made my image tiny (original image was large).

Contain was with some hacks closer to what I wanted than cover, which seems to be that the aspect is maintained but image is scaled to make the smallest-dimension match the screen - i.e. always make the image as big as it can until one of the dimensions would go offscreen...

I tried a bunch of different things, starting over included, but found height was essentially always ignored and would overflow.  (I've been trying to scale a non-widescreen image to be fullscreen on both, broken-aspect is ok for me).  Basically, the above is what worked for me, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
body {
  background-image:url(../IMAGES/background.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a six year old question with an accepted answer and twelve existing answers it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by explaining how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.appBg {

background-image: url(".../img/background.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto ;
}
```

This one works for me

Answer (score 0):

Background image fix to screens with browser compatibility css

```
.full-screen {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    //for browser compatibility
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there are answers to this your questions but because I was once a victim of this problem and after few search online i was unable to solve it but my fellow hub mate helped me and i feel i should share. 
Examples explained below.

Folders: `web-projects/project1/imgs-journey.png`

```
background-image:url(../imgs/journey.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

My major points is the dots there if you noticed my journey.png is located inside an imgs folder of another folder so you're to add the dot according to the numbers folders where your image is stored. In my case my journey.png image is saved in two folders that's why two dot is used, so i think this may be the problem of background images not showing sometimes in our codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100%;
background-image: url("images/bluedraw.jpg");   
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to some of the answers above but I wouldn't set in the body, it is less flexible that way. If I were you, I would create a container and set the background properties specific to it. This allows the image to scale with the page AND enables it to fully take up the background even in situations where the page size differs drastically from the image proportions, see images at the very bottom as an example.

To create such a container, you can do something similar to the following:

In your html page:

```html
<div class='background-div'></div>
```

In your style sheet:

```css
.background-div {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

The CSS block does the following:

1. Zero out any positioning, ie sets image to start at the top most left corner.
2. We set position to `fixed` in order remove the element from the
   normal document flow.
3. Set image location. You should change it your respective folder.
4. We set background to `cover` which will make the image fit the screen.
5. Lastly, we center the image.

**background style applied to `<div>` container**
[image: background style applied to div container]

**background style applied to `<body>` container**
[image: [![background style applied to body element][2]][2](bordered)]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like what I did with my website:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
background: url("../image/b21.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;

background-size: 100% 100%;

height: 100%;

position: absolute; 

width: 100%;
```