# How to make background image fit browser window size

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and want my front page to have a photo that covers the entire background. I have searched and searched but I can't get my image to fit the screen, it automatically zooms in! I have attached an image of what it looks like, the picture is of a pier and all that shows is a zoomed in corner of the pic. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fit website background image to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925075/fit-website-background-image-to-screen-size)

Comment: hi you can find what you want here https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS

```
html {
background: url(example.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```