# How can I make my background image fit to phone size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

On my desktop my background image fits perfectly and its responsive even when i make the window smaller. When i open it up on my mobile device the image hasn't changed and it's really zoomed in. how can i fix this? This is my current code in css

```
.welcome-area{
    background-image: url(../images/13/Dr-Teals-Banner.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

This is my html Code:

```
 <section class="welcome-area text-center" data-scroll-index="1">
          <div class="overlay-bg-65 flex-center med-padding">
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="welcome-text">
                      <img src="images/logo-animation/logo.gif"><br><br><h5 class="color-ddd fw-400">DR TEAL'S</h5>
                      <h1 class="mb-20px color-fff fw-100 cd-headline clip">

                          <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
                              <b class="is-visible color-gold">Graphic Designer</b>
                              <b class="color-gold">Branding</b>
                              <b class="color-godl">Print</b>
                              <b class="color-gold">Photography</b>
                              <b class="color-gold">Digital</b>
                          </span>
                      </h1>
                      <h6 class="color-ddd fw-400 mb-30px">2019-Present</h6>
                      <a href="https://instagram.com/edisson.alberto/" class="color-fff color-blue-hvr mr-15px"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/edissonhidalgo" class="color-fff color-blue-hvr"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="color-fff fs-35 p-absolute scroll-bottom-btn" data-scroll-nav="2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fit website background image to screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925075/fit-website-background-image-to-screen-size)

Answer (score 1):

You have set your `min-height:100vh`, which means it will always fill up the full height and therefore zoom into the picture.

If you want the image to scale proportionally set the `width: 100%`

Comment: i tried but it didn't work managed to us this and it seems to work 

' height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  //for browser compatibility
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
'