# background image in IE on top of page, not a background

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for a site that looks fine in firefox,chrome, and safari.  IE however, the image shows up on the top of the page.  what am i missing?

```
  #background {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -999; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */
    opacity:.09;
  filter:alpha(opacity=9);
 }


.stretch {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

html:

```
  <div id='background'><img src='<?php echo $bg;?>' class='stretch'></div>
   //rest of page//
```

where $bg is path to a image.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `body {background: ...;}` for the background image?

Comment: IT looks like a wordpress theme or some cms theme, and he wants to use PHP to control the image that is used. Am I right?

Comment: Your HMTL / CSS says that this is not a background image but rather an inline image in a position div.

Comment: Why not use a css `background-image`? e.g. `<div id='background' style='background-image: url(<?php echo $bg;?>);'> </div>`

Comment: The code appears to be from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1208392).

Comment: ahh, yes Ilmari has reason why no background-image.  this isn't wordpress, and yes php to control image.

Comment: For IE `#background { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP in an inline style:

`<div id="background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $bg; ?>);">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve a full page background this will helpful for you.

```
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
```

Good luck!