# CSS Stretch background image to full width

Tags: css

I have a background image which is 1920x579px and I want its width to cover the full screen but not its height because the height would look ugly if stretched until the bottom. Please help me! I really tried everything!

Comment: background-size: 100% auto; maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `background-size: width height;` property.

```
body{
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the image in the css

```
BODY {
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center -100px fixed; 
}
```

the `-100px` can be adjusted to move the image up or down.