# Stretching background of the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to stretch image inside div element.

So on the site: http://fishcacher.sytes.net/ there is background image 
[image]

for "fc-container" div element:

```
.fc-container {
    background-image:url('../images/bg_1400.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;  
    margin:0px; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I need it works exactly like this http://www.htmlite.com/faqEX004.html , but inside my "fc-container" div element. Currently a lot of image is hidden below the bottom bar.

I tried different ways but can't fix that.

Appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Comment: No, it doesn't work , because in that answer it has position fixed and it doesn't scroll together with fc-container div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the your example site, they haven't used CSS alone to create their background, they've used a wrapper that contains a image that is then stretched to fill the whole screen. Here's the required HTML code:

```
<div class="backgroundimagewrapper">
    <img class="backgroundimage" src="http://fishcacher.sytes.net/images/bg_1200.png" />
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
.backgroundimagewrapper{
    position: absolute; /* So we can position our div precisely */
    left: 0; /* Move it to the top-left */
    top: 0;
    z-index: -100; /* Make it appear behind other elements */
    padding: 0; /* Make sure we don't have any white space around the edges */
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Make it fill our whole screen */
    height: 100%;
}
.backgroundimage{
    width: 100%; /* Make the image fill the whole div */
    height: 100%;
 }
```

That's how they've done it on the website you've linked.
Anyway, here's a JSFiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t5m/5/

Comment: No, in your example "<h1>This appears on top!</h1>" is over background, background should be only inside "backgroundimagewrapper" element

Comment: I mean, for example, I have three divs, top, middle and bottom. Background should be stretched only inside middle div...

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/T2t5m/2/ It now has a header and footer div with the image being stretched in the middle

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but now, when I try add anything to content with background it appears below the background, but should be inside, see: http://jsfiddle.net/T2t5m/3/

Comment: I think I've got it now, you want a header and a footer with the image as a background in-between with content over it? Like this: jsfiddle.net/T2t5m/4

Comment: No problem! Any-time!

Answer (score 0):

add these styles to your fc-container

```
position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;
```

Comment: try to put them in styles in div element. 
example: <div class="dsgere" style="top:0px;left:0px"></div>