# Why the background image does not fill the entire div

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code which displays a `SPAN` inside a `DIV` and then another `DIV` under it which displays some texts. The issue I am having is when I resize the browser the texts and the background image gets all out of place.

Here is a screenshot of how the image is not filling up the `DIV`:

[image]

Also, when I resize, the text are all out of place:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="subpageHeaderImageSection">
    <div id="subpageHeaderLeft">
        <!--<img src="theImages/wcu.png" style="z-index: 5; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 10%; width: 194px; width: 185px;"  />
        <span id="quoteText" style="z-index: 4;">
            We Have the Finest Physicians, Staff, and Systems for the Finest Healthcare
        </span>-->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="subpageFooter">
    <div id="subpageFooterLeft">
        <div style="z-index: 15; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000CC;">
            State-Of-The-Art-Technology
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 14; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 35px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
            Our state-of-the-art technology ensures that we provide the finest healthcare. Our practice continuously invests in systems and equipment so that physicians can diagnose problems in the most accurate and efficient manner possible.
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 90px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 13; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 110px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000CC;">
            Advanced Electronic Medical Records
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 12; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 135px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
            Our advanced electronic medical record improves patient care and gives physicians all of the important patient information they need in one place.
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 175px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 11; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 200px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000CC;">
            Premier Radiology Services
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 225px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
            Filmless radiology capabilities provide rapid results and allow physicians to view images on an office computer screen within minutes. Our premier radiology services include MRI, CT scan, ultrasonography, nuclear medicine, bone densitometry and mammography. We offer computer-aided diagnosis (CAD), which is a tool to assist the radiologist in more accurately diagnosing breast disease.
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 310px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 9; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 335px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000CC;">
            Our Employees Make MyMed a Special Place
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 8; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 360px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
            MyMed values each of our employees’ experience, diversity and dedication. Ideas and backgrounds that our employees bring to our company enable us to be more effective in anticipating and exceeding our patients’ needs and expectations. <a class="blueLinks" href="http://www.mymed.com/talented_people.aspx">Click here</a> for the opportunity to meet some of the employees who greatly contribute to our success.
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding-top: 430px; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%;"><hr /></div>
        <div style="z-index: 7; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 455px; font-weight: bold; color: #0000CC;">
            Wide Range Of Insurances
        </div>
        <div style="z-index: 6; position: absolute; left: 0; padding-left: 40px; padding-top: 480px; padding-right: 8px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000;">
            A big advantage to using WESTMED Medical Group is the <a class="blueLinks" href="http://www.mymed.com/participating_insurance.aspx?id=473">wide range of insurance coverage</a> accepted. This means you should be able to keep your doctors even if you find you have to change insurance plans. We care equally about every patient regardless of the insurance provider.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="subpageFooterRight">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#subpageHeaderImageSection {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
}
#subpageHeaderLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../theImages/subpageHeaderImage.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#subpageFooter {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 555px;
    background: url('../theImages/bg_80_w.png');
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFFFFF;
}
#subpageFooterRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#subpageFooterLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}
#quoteText {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'daysregular';
    font-size: 30pt;
}
```

Two things I would really like help with:

1. How can I ensure the background image on the header always fills up the DIV no matter how I resize?
2. How can I ensure the text doesn't come on top of each other like it's doing in the second image?

Comment: Please create jsfiddle/jsbin example :)

Comment: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58AZ7/ (The image issue has been fixed but the text overlaps if not resized to 100%) How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-size: 100% 100%` to fill completely (maybe stretched) 
other wise use `background-size: cover` as @Andras said

Comment: Yes 100% 100% worked but the image is now stretched but it's fine! From the second image, how Do I make it so it appears below the previous one like it shows up in regular page and no matter how much i resize it always stays the same?

Comment: JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/58AZ7 (The image issue has been fixed but the text overlaps if not resized to 100%) How can I fix that?

Comment: The 100% 100% doesn't work in IE8 for some reason. The image is stretched out of the DIV :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size:cover`, and it will fill.

Comment: `background-size: cover` fills up the entire `DIV` but it doesn't resize when the browser is resized.

Comment: I actually had to use `100% 100%` in the value and it worked fine! :) Thanks you any way...