# how to scale an image disproportionally via css?

Tags: html, css

If I got an image, say 100*100px, what I want is to scale this image right into a region whose scale is 100*800px (just for test). I've tried to use `max-height` or `max-width`, but this will just scale the image proportionally, which can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yXA9j/1/).

What should I do to **stretch** the image in order to make it fit into the region? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres what you can do.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXA9j/4/)

Change your `CSS` code to:

```
img {
  width:50px;
  height:800px;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

This will allow to image to stretch in order to fill the height/width

Let me know if this worked!

Answer (score 0):

CSS 3 background-size:

contain

cover

100% 100%

will give you some variations on what you are talking about.

See here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

as you standard image will 100px by 100px;
you can give your img an ID, then use the ID in your CSS to set the height en width.
max-height or max-width will only set the maximum of both. not change it

```
#img {
  width:50px;
  height:800px;
}
```