# css place background image for div for 100% width

Tags: css

All I want is to place background image for div for 100% width. Could you please help me to find my mistake.

**html**

```
  <div class="slogan_background"> 
    <h2>Slogan</h2> 
    </div>
```

**css**

```
 background-image: url("../img/bg.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
 width:100%;
 min-height: 526px;
```

Comment: there are spaces on the left and right sides. If i remove no-repeat, it shows 100%

Comment: you image size may be not the width of the div.

Comment: no-repeat means the image is repeated so if you look close then you will see the part of the same image.. but I agree with the answer below first try that if it solves your issue.

Comment: yes i know that the size is smaller and that no-repeats means do not repeat

Comment: Take a look at `background-size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, this might help:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good but maybe you didn't set height and width for body tag. Try adding this to your css

```
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Also set padding and margin to 0 to remove spaces from the side

```
.slogan_background{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: i added as you said but the result is the same

Comment: I tried editing the template and it works good without any spacing on side

Comment: @Nakib the background image is not stretched the way you expect.. you need `background-size` property

Answer (score 1):

Add the
 `backgroun-size:100% 100%;`
[duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)