# Set background in React.js using style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to add a background image in React.js by using a style definition, which works:

```
let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'    
let styles = {
        root: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
        ...
```

[image]

As you can see, the image repeats in x-direction. So I wanted to extend it by:

```
let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'
let styles = {
    root: {
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
        backgroundImage: {
            flex: 1,
            resizeMode: 'cover', // or 'stretch'
        },
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    ...
```

But the image is not loaded anymore:

[image]

So how to set the background image and adjust it in React.js?

Comment: `backgroundImage` is repeated, but object keys cannot repeat. merge the 2.

Comment: @dandavis thanks, how can I merge them? Using url: 'xxx' or src: 'xxx'?

Comment: maybe the backgroundImage has a url property? not sure of react's mapping, but i know you can't repeat keys. can you use CSS instead? you can template <style> tags ya know...

Answer (score 17):

This works:

```
    let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'
    let styles = {
        root: {
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            overflow: 'hidden',
        },
        ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Clarifing another answer

```html
let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'
let styles = {
    root: {
       backgroundImage: `url(${ imgUrl })`
       backgroundRepeat  : 'no-repeat',
       backgroundPosition: 'center',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use an image as background, is better to use the 'backgroundImage' property.

If you use the 'background' property, this may cause issues on reloading the component (e.g. 'cover' attribute will not apply properly).

Solution proposed:

```
let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'; 

<div className = 'Component-Bg' 
     style = {{ backgroundImage: `url(${imgUrl})`,
                backgroundSize: 'cover', 
                backgroundPosition: 'center center',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              }}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried somthing like this :

```
let imgUrl = 'images/berlin.jpg'
let styles = {
root: {

    background: 'url('+ imgUrl + ') noRepeat center center fixed',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
}
```

Inspired from this post: [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Comment: the above unfortunately is not completely right - BUT you gave me the right direction:

Comment: Cool. Should you post your final code for the other who will ask ?

Comment: @Marcel can you post the complete answer for other people ? Thank you!

Comment: @all You can find Marcel's approach right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414070/1885946