# Loading Image from css Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I currently have a css file which cuts out different images with different dimension from an image file.

sprite.css

```
sprite
{
    background:url(/app/images/sprite.png) no-repeat top left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    float:left
}
.sprite.followed
{
    background-position:0 0
}
.sprite.feedback
{
    background-position:0 -35px
}
.sprite.content_share
{
    background-position:0 -70px
}
.sprite.become_fan
{
    background-position:0 -105px
}
.sprite.articleread
{
    background-position:0 -140px
}
.sprite.voting
{
    background-position:0 -175px
}
.sprite.visits
{
    background-position:0 -210px
}
.sprite.star_rate
{
    background-position:0 -245px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px
}
.sprite.yvideo
{
    background-position:0 -279px
}
.sprite.whatsapp
{
    background-position:0 -314px
}
.sprite.tweet
{
    background-position:0 -349px
}
.sprite.share
{
    background-position:0 -384px
}
.sprite.review_live
{
    background-position:0 -419px
}
.sprite.review_like
{
    background-position:0 -454px
}
.sprite.message
{
    background-position:0 -489px
}
.sprite.like
{
    background-position:0 -524px
}
.sprite.sync
{
    background-position:0 -559px
}
```

I'm loading the above mentioned in a js file mentioned below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../../css/sprite.css';

const ActionListArray = React.createClass({

    render() {

        var fontFamily = this.props.fontFamily;
        var fontSize = this.props.fontSize;
        var coinName = this.props.coinName;
var actionListArray = this.props.data.map(function(text, index){
                        return <Col xs={12} md={6} key={index} style={fontSize}><div style={fontFamily}><div className={text.sprite}></div>{text.shortText} = {text.value} {coinName}(s)</div></Col>;
                      });

        return (<div>{actionListArray}</div>);
    }

});

export default ActionListArray;
```

`text.sprite` contains the class names mentioned in the css file.

My problem -> When I run it, the div is generated with the class name but no image appears in the div.

What might be the issue? Any other way of fetching it in the js file?

Constraints ->

1. Since, I have to port the project into reactjs, I have been provided a css file which contains the icons. I now have to include it in the ported Reactjs project. So, is there any other way which doesn't require a change of the css file?
2. If no, then please mention the best method

**EDIT 1**

This is my console
[image: Error Photo]

My Directory is

```
app
   components
       tabsContent
           ActionListArray.js
   css
       sprite.css
   images
       sprite.png
```

**EDIT 2**
Apparently, there was a need of a fiddle.
Here's a sample implying the same code.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75740/

Comment: check console you can see what exact error

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413862/set-background-in-react-js-using-style/36414020

Comment: Maybe some issue with path of the image. Did u see image being loaded in the Networks tab in Developer Tools window??

Comment: try putting the path of the image in double quotes `background:url("/app/images/sprite.png") no-repeat top left;`

Comment: @iamsaksham I guess that might be the issue, I cannot see `sprite.png` in the Networks tab. Is the aforementioned way the correct way to call the file?

Comment: Yes, try using it and let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: @iamsaksham No, still unable to call

Comment: Try using absolute path `( "../images/sprite.png")` It should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140037/discussion-between-iamsaksham-and-ciedzs).