# CSS - Background image stretch horizontally and repeat vertically?

Tags: css, background-image

Using `background-size: cover` I am able to make the background stretch to fit the full width of the page.

Using `repeat-y` I am able to make the background repeat or tile vertically, to the full height of the page.

Is there any way to combine these two effects? Unfortunately they don't seem to work together (at least in Chrome). It appears that I can either stretch in both directions with `background-size: cover`, or not stretch in the x direction but repeat in the y direction.

Edit: Using `background-size: 100% Npx` (where N is the height of the image) I can accomplish the above, but it skews the background image as it's only stretched in one direction. Is there a way to keep it scaling proportionally?

Comment: you can do that with only background-size:100%;

Comment: @Chiller you are correct but you need to specify both x and y. i.e. `background-size: 100% auto`

Comment: @ probablly you are right but if you see here it works without adding auto https://jsfiddle.net/qp4093h2/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Instead of cover, use `background-size: 100% auto;` to size the background image to full browser width while maintaining aspect ratio for its height. Use this in conjunction with `background-repeat: repeat-y;` to tile it vertically.

Comment: Since the background-size x is 100% width it shouldn't repeat-x so you actually don't need to specify repeat-y, just let it default.... but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: for those searching for what I was -- the `auto` attribute above is specifying a height, so if you put in a fixed height like in the code `background-size: 100% 150px;` then your image will stretch horizontally while maintaining the 150px dimension.

Comment: In my case it is not working, I change it to background-size: 100% calc(100%), and it worked for me

Comment: As @Rishi0405 comments, it doesn't work if the image is higher horizontally than the screen. I needed to stretch it, so calc(100%) worked fine