# I need to put my content overtop my background image and also use no repeat

Tags: background

This is my website: http://bigredsportfishing.com/

As you can see, I have a repeated image and I need that to stretch AND have my logo on the top.  Any suggestions?

Here is what I am using.  A simple html code. 
`

Big Red Sport Fishing

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: {html}
{head}
{title>Big Red Sport Fishing</title>
<div align="center">

<body background="backgroundmain.jpg" no-repeat;>
<img src="logo.jpg">

</div>

</body>
</html}

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat;` for no repeats

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)

Answer (score 1):

You may put css style in body tag

```
.background{
  background-image: url(backgroundmain.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and use

```
<body class="background"></body>
```

Comment: Superior answer to my own. Well put.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the style of `background-size: cover;` to your background image, it will always be exactly big enough to fit the browser window. Looks like your logo will already be on top from my understanding of your question. So that style should do it.