# Image not fitting into WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, css, wkwebview

Trying to display the below request.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    let htmlString = "<p><a href=\"https://miro.medium.com/max/3336/1*iGyyen2re8-dgQJlL65axw.png\"><img src=\"https://miro.medium.com/max/3336/1*iGyyen2re8-dgQJlL65axw.png\" class=\"alignnone size-full\"></a></p>\n<p></p>\n<p>Vijay Chandrasekhar: \"Robin Uthappa, Faiz Gaza's have already users kookaburra bats before in an international game\"<br><br>Sivan dune just got his t29I cap from Ravi Shastri. He becomes the 82nd cricketer to represent Indian in the format. </p>"
    var headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=0.65, maximum-scale=0.65, minimum-scale=0.65'></header>"
    headerString.append(htmlString)
    webView.loadHTMLString(headerString, baseURL: nil)

}
```

Unfortunately, the image size appering in WKWebview is very huge. Because of that, horizontal scrolling happening. But, i don't want this behaviour.

Expecting the image size should be same fit into WKWebView.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider one of 2 solutions:

1. just stretch it using CSS `width: 100%` (height will be calculated automatically)
2. use it as a background image for the whole page and stretch it using CSS `background-size: 100%` or `background-size: cover`

Actually see this:
[Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)