# Unable to scale image on mobile

Tags: html, css, scaling

I have an image that I am trying to scale as the screen size reduces. On desktop it work fine for resolution 1336 x 625 but as soon as the screen reduces to 500 X 625 the image does not scale properly and edges are cut down. I tried putting max-width and the position. Still it doesn't work. What I need to change to make it work.

Css code

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
   font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
 background-color: #CCC; 
}

.card-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
        width: 650px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 15px;
        transition: transform 1s;
}


.card-wrapper:hover .card {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        box-shadow: 1 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
        
}


.card-front{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 15px;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        background: linear-gradient(white,white);
}

.up {
        width: 30%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: right;
    
}

.up img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    }

.up span {
   text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #0d5692;
}

.down {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    height: 30%;
    color: black;
    top: 170px;
    left: 5px;
}

.down-content {
      
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin: 10px 0;
}

.person {
    font-family: "Yu Gothic",UI-Semibold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(102, 0, 51);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.designation {
    font-family: "Yu Gothic",UI-Semibold;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.address {
    font-family: "Arial Nova Light";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.phone {
    font-family: "Arial Nova Light";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.card-back {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: linear-gradient(white,white);
}

.back-up {
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
}

.back-up img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    }

.back-down {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    color: black;
    top: 140px;
    left: 5px;
}

.back-designation {
    font-family: "Meiryo";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.back-person {
    font-family: "Meiryo UI";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.back-address {
    font-family: "Meiryo";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.back-phone {
    font-family: "Meiryo";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(77, 0, 102);
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-Origional.css" />
    <title>Business Card</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-front">
                                <div class="up">
                                        <img src="images/logo.png" />
                                        <!-- <h4><span>AWS Architect</span></h4> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="down">
                                    <div class="person down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                 <h2> Jarich Vansteenberge </h2>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="designation down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                 <h2> Manager </h2>
                                                 <h2> Technology & Innovation </h2>
                                                 <h2> Information & Digital Solutions </h2>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="address down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                  <p> Astrazeneca K.K. </p>
                                                  <p> Grand Front Osaka Tower B 3-1,</p>
                                                  <p> Ofuka-chu, Kita-ku, Osaka 530-0011, Japan </p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="phone down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                <p> Mobile +81-80-6222-4967 </p>
                                                <p> E-mail jarich.vansteenberge@astrazeneca.com </p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-back" >
                                <div class="back-up">
                                        <img src="images/logo.png" width="150"/>
                                        <!-- <h4><span>AWS Architect</span></h4> -->
                                </div>
                                 <div class="back-down">
                                    <div class="back-designation down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                 <h2> インフォメーション＆デジタルソリューションズ本部 </h2>
                                                 <h2> テクノロジーとイノベーション </h2>
                                                 <h2> マネージャー </h2>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back-person down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                 <h2> バンステーンベルグ　ジャリコ </h2>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back-address down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                  <p> アストラゼネカ </p>
                                                  <p> グランフロント大阪タワーB 3-1,</p>
                                                  <p> 大阪市北区大深法律事務所530-0011 </p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="back-phone down-content">
                                            <div>
                                                <p> 携帯電話番号 +81-80-6222-4967 </p>
                                                <p> E-mail jarich.vansteenberge@astrazeneca.com </p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just make a search inside SO and you will find a lot of question

Answer (score 0):

```
.responsive {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
```

}

you can add these class to the image and it will work fine

Comment: No working. I added <img src="images/logo.png" class="responsive"/> and <img src="images/logo.png" class="responsive" /> and in Css i added.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}....

still not working

Comment: i request you to remove class related to up and then try

Comment: Not working. I tried removing class up from html file

Comment: You can have a look at this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only?rq=1