# Centering a background image, using CSS

Tags: css

I want to center a background image. There is no div used, this is the [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) style:

```
body{
    background-position:center;
    background-image:url(../images/images2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

The above CSS tiles all over and does center it, but half the image is not seen, it just kind of moves up. What I want to do is center the image. Could I adopt the image to view even on a 21" screen?

Comment: Now that would depend on the size of the image and the size of the browser, wouldn't it?

Comment: @nikc +1, I am aware, but need to know if there was a work around

Answer (score 390, accepted):

```
background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

That should work.

If not, why not make a `div` with the image and use `z-index` to make it the background? This would be much easier to center than a background image on the body.

Other than that try:

`background-position: 0 100px;/*use a pixel value that will center it*/` Or I think you can use 50% if you have set your body `min-height` to 100%.

```
body{

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image:url(../images/images2.jpg);
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: It does centralize, but displays only half the screen, I wish stackoverflow had an option to attach screenshots

Comment: You could make a screenshot and upload it to your server or a free pic hosting site like photobucket.com, or make a temporary example at www.jsfiddle.net and post a link for us. From what you've said, the image is 1600x1200 and most screen resolutions don't go that high, try resizing your image to fit. I use a widescreen monitor at 1440x900 for example.

Comment: screenshot - http://imagevat.com/picview.php?ig=6179
I am not sure how to upload images to jsfiddle, if you can help me out there
http://www.jsfiddle.net/yWrQP/

Comment: To add an image to jsfiddle, just use the full http path EX: `background-image:url(http://www.myurl.com/images/image.jpg);` put that in the CSS.

Comment: I dont have the server to do it, but used an imagehosting site, but still check it out now

Comment: I checked it out, I saw what you're going for, and am actually kinda stumped as to why it doesn't work. I edited my answer, try setting your body min-height.

Comment: I thought it was a browser used, and checked on IE 8, FF, Chrome.

Comment: Check cross browser compatibility after you have it working in FF, did you set the `min-height`?

Comment: min-height worked, I gave it the height of the image since I know it, probably have to use jquery to do it.  Now why is there a 5px space on top.  I did top:0px; does not seem to work though, any ideas?
check jsfiddle.net/yWrQP

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't do anything, when you click run it should show up your result in the bottom right frame, please amend your fiddle. Here's an example of one I've been messing with http://jsfiddle.net/waFC8/.

Answer (score 26):

I use this code, it works nice

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: black url(back2.png) center center no-repeat;;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hey Victor, I used your code a lot, but it look it doesn't work now. I added background-attachment: fixed; but it is not working on my iPad browser...

Comment: Only `-webkit-background-size` exists from the special declarations though.

Answer (score 22):

I think [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) is what is wanted:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: How come the double center center work?
Anyway it does not solve the issue, still the same

Comment: @Jean: look at the specs, background-position actually can actually take 2 values (horizontal and vertical). http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position

Comment: @rob its not working, the image is tiling.  The image is a 1600x1200 and my screen size is 1280x800

Comment: `background-image` only takes one argument. You need to specify `background-repeat: no-repeat` as a separate instruction

Comment: @Jean you can't resize a background image (yet). It's possible in CSS 3 but that isn't supported widely enough yet. `center center` in tandem with `background-repeat: no-repeat` should do what you ask for - center the image.

Comment: Guys, please try my code with a 1600x1200 on localhost, you will understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: @Jean is your problem the re-sizing of the image?

Comment: it could be the page content isnt big enough to display the content, add a `min-height` and `height` to the body CSS too to handle this.  Lastly, you could use javascript to get the screen height and pick a correct image to display in the background of the body, so you would always see the correct image.

Comment: If I remove the syntax

 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;


THen the image is displayed from left and tiled

Comment: @Jean but why would you remove the syntax?

Comment: @Jean ahh, I see now from your screen shot. You need to give the `body` a `min-height` of `100%` so it extends across the full screen. That may sort it.

Comment: @pekka, it did sort out, but there is another problem now check http://www.jsfiddle.net/yWrQP/4/

Comment: @Jean can you describe the problem? I don't see it.

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Dore_woodcut_Divine_Comedy_01.jpg/481px-Dore_woodcut_Divine_Comedy_01.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

```css
html{
height:100%
}

body{
background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8b/Dore_woodcut_Divine_Comedy_01.jpg/481px-Dore_woodcut_Divine_Comedy_01.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's an error in your code. You're using a mix of full syntax and shorthand notation on the background-image property.This is causing the no-repeat to be ignored, since it's not a valid value for the background-image property.

```
body{   
    background-position:center;
    background-image:url(../images/images2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Should become one of the following:

```
body{
    background:url(../images/images2.jpg) center center no-repeat;
}
```

or

```
body
{
    background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

EDIT: For your image 'scaling' issue, you might want to look at [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background).

Comment: 'background:url(../images/images2.jpg) center center no-repeat;' does not work, since the syntax is wrong

And the others do not work either

Answer (score 4):

simply replace

```
background-image:url(../images/images2.jpg) no-repeat;
```

with

```
background:url(../images/images2.jpg)  center;
```

Comment: This repeated the image. On chrome, need center and no-repeat specified.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `background-position: center top;`

This will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
```

Does not vertically center the background image when using a html 4.01 'STRICT' doctype.

Adding:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Should fix the problem

(So Alexander is right)

Answer (score 3):

```
background-position: center center;
```

doesn't work for me without...

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

using both centered my image on x and y axis

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your not satisfied with the answers above then use this

```
    * {margin: 0;padding: 0;}

    html
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body
    {
        background-image: url("background.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: 80%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Used display and margin properties and it worked.

```
.background-image {
  background: url('yourimage.jpg') no-repeat;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: whateveryouwantpx;
  width: whateveryouwantpx;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Answer (score -2):

The only thing that worked for me is..

```
margin: 0 auto
```