# How to keep the center of the background image in html css

Tags: html, css

So i made a html page with background image of a person on it like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Emo.jpg). I want to make it responsive, so that when I open the web on the phone, the person is on the center (shows the center of the image). For now the output shows the left part of the image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbj08.jpg). Is there any part in the css that i can change to make that happen?

Comment: Use `background-position: center`

Comment: It would help us give a full answer that would work for devices of any aspect-ratio if you could put up a small snippet of code which includes your image. As the person is central in the horizontal direction background-position: center will work well for that but they are not central in the vertical direction so there will have to be some thought given to how to position the image vertically on a narrow device in landscape mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering a background image, using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643305/centering-a-background-image-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML code like below. You may see the [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rajuahmed/gq53eL1n/1/)

```
<div class="imageDiv">
       <img class="imageClass" src="../yourfile/" />
</div>
```

Then try with the following CSS:

```
div.imageDiv {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:45%;
    max-height:45%;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    overflow:visible;
}
img.imageClass {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin-top:-50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the image given in the question (which is a screenshot, but I assume contains most of the actual image) I think it may be possible that using just plain CSS without regard to exactly where the figure's head is in relation to the image dimensions will be good enough for your needs.

This snippet uses both background-size: cover - to ensure the whole of the element (in this case the body) is covered and background-position: center center - to get (roughly) the head in the center both vertically and horizontally.

It would be useful to check using your actual image rather than the mockup from the screenshot but hopefully this snippet shows the basic idea:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Emo.jpg);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```