# Is it possible to shrink an image and make it your background all in css?

Tags: css

I have a div, and I want to make a whole background image fit inside the div, even though the image is a little bigger than the div, how would I go about shrinking this dynamically?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: You can't do that with CSS only. It's not for image processing. To do that you need to use a script, server-side(PHP,JSP,etc) or Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is possible in CSS3 but not currently in CSS2

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size

This is also a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Comment: Even so, it would be best to pre-size the image on the server side.  Regardless, +1 for answering the qustion.