# Photo as website home page background dimensions?

Tags: image, photoshop

hope this question is ok on stackoverflow. I want to use a photo as the background for the homepage of a website. The photo will be take up the entire page. However i don't know what resolution i should make the photo. I was thinking 1920 x 1200px so that people with 24 inch screen don't see the 'ends' of the photo. However is that big enough? I'm worried about the site looking ok on screens larger than 24 inches.

Also anyone know how i should optimize the photo so it loads as fast as possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Overall, this seems to be a question of trade-offs.  The better the resolution, the slower the page load for a do-nothing page.  Is it worth the slow-down to have the better resolution and avoid pixellation?

Also, I think you're asking the wrong question, since a 24-inch screen can be in multiple resolutions.

I would approach this in the following manner:

1. what is the largest resolution you MUST have your photo look "good" on?   Then make your photo that resolution.  If 24" is your target, look at what resolutions this size monitor "typically" supports and target that.
2. What number of colors you want?  (or perhaps b&w / grayscale).  If you reduce the number of colors (preferably to "web-safe" colors), you can load faster with the same resolution.
3. A program like Photoshop (or Gimp) will probably give you the most power in tuning these parameters.

Do you care if only a portion of the photo displays when your viewer has a smaller window?

I know this isn't a cut and dried answer, but these things seldom are (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that will work on most modern browsers, you will need to place the image in a div with a z-index less than the rest of your page (see: [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background))

As far as creating a 1920x1200 photo that will compress to a small size, I would recommend trying a smaller size (e.g. 960x600) and see if it looks okay on your 24-inch screen. There are many programs that will let you specify file size for your compression (e.g. FastStone Resizer) so you can experiment and see what is acceptable. In general, photos with less detail and/or color-depth will compress better.

Another problem you are going to run into is aspect ratio. Even assuming that your web-site is always opened in a full screen browser and not a window, sometimes that screen is going to be 16:9 ratio and sometimes 4:3. You could try to create an photo that has a nice 4:3 ratio "sweet-spot" in the center and adjust your div using some Javascript based on the current window aspect-ratio.