# Resize 1 background image for multiple div containers on a page

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

I have this one super fancy background image that needs to scale into being the background for 3 boxes on one page, 100% height/width. Is this possible?

NOT 1 background scaling to be the whole page background.

But

|   Box 1 (50x50) gets background|         |   Box 2 (20x20) gets background | etc.

I'd like to assign class "background" to all of these divs, and have 1 background image used that scales based on the dimensions of the div. Its a square, and its ok if it looks slightly distorted

FYI - this is a panels page drupal layout.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background. In short only via CSS 3 but that link provides a workaround that might work for you as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your browser restrictions but there is a CSS3 property called `background-size`. You would simply set this to `background-size: 100% 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.background img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

This will make the image tretch to fit div's height @ 100% height & scale naturally with width:auto.