# CSS: Stretching image to 100% width

Tags: css, background, background-image

Hi all
I am trying to strech the background of my side to fit the width. I only found big workarounds in the internet. Is there not one single command for this?

```
body {
    background-image: url(money.jpg); 
}
```

Thanks for the answers.
Doonot

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [background-size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974665.aspx) like the one used below,

```
body {
  background-image: url(money.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Some useful links :

- [Scale background image style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236365/is-there-a-way-to-scale-background-image-style)
- [Stretch and Scale a CSS image Background - With CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only)

Answer (score 7):

If you have a CSS3 browser you can use `background-size` ([read more about background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)):

```
body {
    background-image: url(money.jpg); 
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately this won't work in IE 6-8. IE 9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari it will work fine.