# How do I get a background to stretch to the full width?

Tags: html, css

I have to fix by HTML page's background for full width, but the height of the background is not as per my design. How can I fix it?

CSS Code:

```
html {
    background: url(images/body_bg.jpg') no-repeat top left fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Use a full size image instead.

Comment: remove backgroun-size:cover,it should be stretch your image as per the browser width and height..and give large bg image.

Comment: You have a type in your code you are missing a `'` in your path declaration

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `'` in the `url`

```
background: url('images/body_bg.jpg') no-repeat top left fixed;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/zgCB2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use background-size like the one used below,

```
body {
  background-image: url(image1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Some useful links :

[Scale background image style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236365/is-there-a-way-to-scale-background-image-style)

[Stretch and Scale a CSS image Background - With CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-in-the-background-with-css-only)