# Stretch background image css?

Tags: html, css, background

```
<td class="style1" align='center' height='35'>
  <div style='overflow: hidden; width: 230px;'>
    <a class='link' herf='' onclick='topic(<?=$key;?>)'>
      <span id='name<?=$key;?>'><?=$name;?></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

This is my CSS script

```css
.style1 {
  background-image: url('http://localhost/msite/images/12.PNG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
}
```

I want to stretch the `background-image` all over the `<td>` cell

Comment: Just a note that stretching raster images degrades the quality.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: @wdm: quality degradation won't happen if it's an svg.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

```css
.style1 {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

- Safari 3+
- Chrome Whatever+
- IE 9+
- Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
- Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

In addition you can try this for an IE solution

```css
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
zoom: 1;
```

Credit to this article by Chris Coyier
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: this working fine but i want to stretch the height only how can i do that

Comment: thanks for help it working when i change that in your code `-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;` it works as i want ... thank u

Comment: Another IE8 and lower solution: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Comment: worked for me after changing `background-size: cover;` to ` background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: I needed a fixed height (130px) and full width. This worked: `background: url("images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center 0 fixed;` and `background-size: 100% 130px;` (etc.). Centering the height (as in the answer) would hide the background if it was short enough.

Comment: Worked without `fixed` since it was used in a 3D object. Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Answer (score 71):

CSS3: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

```css
.style1 {
  ...
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

You can specify just width or height with:

```css
background-size: 100% 50%;
```

Which will stretch it 100% of the width and 50% of the height.

---

**Browser support:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly for me - I tried the other answers and a series of different techniques. But this was so simple and worked instantly. Thank you :D

Answer (score 11):

You can't stretch a background image (until CSS 3).

You would have to use absolute positioning, so that you can put an image tag inside the cell and stretch it to cover the entire cell, then put the content on top of the image.

```css
table {
  width: 230px;
}

.style1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
}

.bg {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg .linkcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="10">
  <tr>
    <td class="style1">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/20/20" alt="" />
        <div class="linkcontainer">
          <a class="link" href="#">
            <span>Answer</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1, correct. It is also a good idea to wrap the `<img>` with a `<div>` having `position: relative;` and maximum width/height. The TD itself is not relative positioned in all browsers, if any.

Comment: I was struggling with IE, +1 for that

Answer (score 10):

I think what you are looking for is

```css
.style1 {
  background: url('http://localhost/msite/images/12.PNG');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use downloaded images, it took half a day to figure out this.
Make a "images" folder add it to main folder.

**CSS:**

```
background-images: url(/images/{imagename}.jpg);
background-repeat: no repeat; (if repeat)
background-size: cover;
```

Good day :D

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `background-size: cover;` is

```css
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This ended up working better for my purposes.

Here's the MDN documentation: [MDN documentation on background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Resizing_background_images)

Answer (score -9):

Just paste this into your line of codes:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```