# stretch image background on a div or full backgound image in a div

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure

```
<div id="bg">

</div>
```

and a css

```
#bg{
    background: transparent url(images/bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
   }
```

as you can see from the above codes, this 'background-size: 100%;' should make the background image in the div(#bg) fill the whole container of (#bg) but unfortunately, it doesnt work at all even i also tried 'background-size: cover;' or 'background-size: contain;' but still no lucks, nothing works. Is there any way or alternative way that I could make the background image in the div(#bg) full or will fill the container or will stretch proportionally as what the width and height of the div(#bg)?

Comment: see possible duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are forgetting a parameter in your property declaration

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MYMEt/)

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Explanation: You are using `background-size: 100%;` which will suffice only for `x` and not for `y` so you need to have 2 `100%`, 1 for the `x` and other for `y`

Comment: yay! it works like charm! brilliant! i been implemented the above answers before but I cant believe i didnt remember it to be my reference in my future works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JuliverGalleto You welcome :) btw even `cover` works, but it's a different concept, so `cover != 100% 100%` :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have this solution background-size:100% 100%;

But it doesn't work in all browsers, if you want the fix for IE8,7 and 6 (I think) you ca try this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```