# Background Image Isn't Stretching

Tags: css, background

Im trying to figure out how to correctly fit my background image to my website. It keeps showing the same image a dozen times and I've tried searching for some stretch codes but none of them seemed to work.

```
/* Reset     ================================================================================= */
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

body          { background:url(../images/bg-body.png) 0 0 repeat; font:12px/1.55 Arial,       Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#7b7b7b; text-align:center; }

img           { border:0; vertical-align:top; }

a             { color:#950000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover       { text-decoration:underline; }
:focus        { outline:0; }
```

Comment: This might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
body          { background:url(../images/bg-body.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
                background-size:cover;
```

}

Comment: I already have done that and all it shows is the image as is 177 X 178 pixels. I need it to stretch and cover the whole websites background.