# Full width Background Image - Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I wish to achieve parts of my web page to have a background image that spreads the full with of the page, no white space at the edges. Is this possible? Im using foundation 5 framework.

html

```
  <div class="row"  id="wrapper">
    <div class="large-12  columns">
      <div class="kickstart"><img src="img/kick-start.png">
        <p class="getfit"><img src="img/get-fit.png"></p>
        <p class="home-text"> BodyMetrix Personal Training is a new company, based in South London, aiming to bring one-on-one training sessions and personalised exercise and nutrition plans. </p>
        <p class="get-contact"><img src="img/get-contact-btn.png"></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    background-image: url("../img/home-img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 0;


}
.kickstart {

    padding: 30px;
}
.getfit {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.home-text {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stretch background image css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

You can give `#wrapper` a width of `100%`, or change your HTML to:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12  columns">
      <div class="kickstart"><img src="img/kick-start.png">
        <p class="getfit"><img src="img/get-fit.png"></p>
        <p class="home-text"> BodyMetrix Personal Training is a new company, based in South London, aiming to bring one-on-one training sessions and personalised exercise and nutrition plans. </p>
        <p class="get-contact"><img src="img/get-contact-btn.png"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a `div` is a block element, it will take `width:100%` as default. As long as it isn't in an already existing `.row` class, it will be `100%`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#wrapper {
    background-image: url("../img/home-img.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the background-size property to adjust the size of your background. in your situation you want it to cover the whole screen

**Try the code below:**

```
#wrapper { 
  background: url("../img/home-img.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 0;
}
```