# Scale icon from icon grid

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I have a grid of icons, where each row is a different icon and each column is a different shade. The grid of icons is stored in a `.png` format, like this:

[image]

To access a specific icon I have the following in my CSS and html : `<i class="icon type1 blue>...</i>` This works really well but the issue is I need to make the icons a bit smaller so I made my png 75% smaller. But now the issue is that it's showing the same icon but it's showing half of the blue icon and half the gray icon, like this:[image]

How can I show only the blue icon at a scale of 75%? Here is the CSS code where the image (at full size is set):

```
.icon{
  background-image: url('images/icons.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  heigh: 28px;
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: You'll have to adjust the values of `background-position` set in `.type1` and `.blue`.

Comment: you need to change the size of the block also by 75%.  According to `math` that value is 21px.  adjust your block height and width to 21px.  also make sure your background positions increment by 21 as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
background: url(images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

see: [Stretch background image css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css)

or you can also try `background-size: 100%;` in css3

Answer (score 0):

try something in this format

```
background-image: url('images/icons.png') leftposition topposition;
```

left position and topposition will depend on your sprite image(grip of icons)

for example

```
 background-image: url('images/icons.png') -28px 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses one sprite file and instead of resizing the sprite "physically," individual icons are resized using CSS.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89mGj/.

HTML:

```
<ul class = "regular">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class = "regular small">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS for `.regular`:

```
.regular > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: url(http://i59.tinypic.com/v4crk2.png)
                no-repeat
                -340px -280px/680px;
}

.regular:not(.small) > li:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-position: -30px -321px;
}

.regular:not(.small) > li:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-position: -30px -485px;
}
```

The approach is basic.  A sprite is used as a background-image that does not repeat.  Then, for each list item only the background-position of the sprite is changed to display an appropriate icon.

Here's CSS to display smaller icons:

```
.regular.small > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background-position: -255px -210px;
    background-size: 510px;
}

.regular.small > li:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-position: -23px -241px;
}

.regular.small > li:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-position: -23px -363px;
}
```

The background-position coordinates and background-size are multiplied by 0.75 to create smaller icons (i.e., 680px * 0.75 = 510px).