# CSS Background Doesn't Extend to Bottom of Browser

Tags: html, css

So I have a simple little project I'm making, which has a gradient background. However, upon loading up the website, it looks like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkv6H.jpg)

And, as you can see, it doesn't extend to the bottom of the screen. What is the cause of this? Here is my stylesheet:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.bg-image {
  background-image: url('../bg/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 800px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

}
.container p {
  margin: 1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}
.container {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  top: 175px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container ul {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 600x;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.logo img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: The *only* `height` you are setting in your CSS is the `800px` for `.bg-image`. If your screen is bigger than `800px`, your image won't reach the bottom. Also, you're using a lot of other fixed heights. For example, your `.container img` has `max-height: 400px`. Considering you don't provide your markup, it's hard to tell where each element sits, but this could restrict the height even further.

Comment: Check out this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css

Comment: Give us your markup