# Set background image to full screen in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set a background image in React but it only covers about 75% of the height.

It seems that the component doesn't take up all of the height.

What's the solution?

In index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In index.css:

```
html, body, .Login-component {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In Login.js:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className='Login-component'>
    );
}
```

In Login.css

```
.Login-component {
    background: url(../static/login-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The end result: [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TbD.png)

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Questions that don't show what you have tried are too broad, there are many solutions to this problem.

Comment: Edit: Added the code :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using the specific property values.

In Index.css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

In Login.css:

```
.Login-component {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url(../static/login-bg.jpg);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 49):

Use vh and vw properties:

```
const styles = {
    container: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 17):

The image should be inside your src folder besides that, inside your component you do the following.-

```
const imgMyimageexample = require('../assets/imageexample.jpg');
const divStyle = {
  width: '88%',
  height: '800px',
  backgroundImage: `url(${imgMyimageexample})`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover'   <---- This is important
};

export default class Mycomponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cComponent" style={divStyle} >
        <h1 align="center">Some header example</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't work with the screen more than 800px, will it?

Comment: @YukiTanka maybe you can do a height: '100%' ?

Answer (score 0):

While it is hard to troubleshoot without any code, check the root element to which your react component is being rendered to. Setting `height: '100%'` in the style of your component will be in the context of it's parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the CSS.

This might be what you are looking for:

```
<Component style={{ minHeight: '100%' }} />
```

If you meant that the background image is not covering the whole height, then add a className to your component, import the CSS where you'll do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662735/stretch-background-image-css)

Answer (score 0):

An answer by Jorge Carretero is helpful and in case it still doesn't work for you, try adding **default**

```
const imgMyimageexample = require('../assets/imageexample.jpg').default;
const divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url(${imgMyimageexample})`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover'   <---- This is important
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Full typescript solution:

```js
import imgBG from "../assets/imgBG.jpg";

interface imgStyleType {
   backgroundImage: string;
   backgroundPosition: string;
   backgroundSize: string;
   backgroundRepeat: string;
   width: string;
   height: string;
}

const imgStyle: imgStyleType = {
   backgroundImage: `url(${imgBG})`,
   backgroundPosition: "center",
   backgroundSize: "cover",
   backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
   width: "100vw",
   height: "100vh",
};

export default function ImgBG() {
   return (
      <>
         <div style={imgStyle} />
      </>
   );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.Login-component{

    background-image:url(path) ;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
  
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this solves the problem, and possibly how it's different from the other answers?