# How do I make an image smaller with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have [this page](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/) and I have users uploading an icon image for the industries and they are uploading a bigger image. I want to resize it via [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and it's cutting it when changing it in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29). To see what I mean, select "retail" from the top dropdown "Select Industry Category" and then select "General" from "Select Business Type" and you will see the oddly shaped image. It needs to be 56 pixels * 52 pixels.

Here is my HTML:

```
<span class="icon select-business-icon" style="background-image: url(http://posnation.com/shop_possystems/image/data/icons/retail.png);">&nbsp;</span>
```

I tried in the CSS to set the width and height to the desired measurements, but all it did was truncate the image and not resize.

Answer (score 22):

Here's what I've done:

```
.resize {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}

.resize {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

<img class="resize" src="example.jpg"/>
```

This will keep the image aspect ratio the same.

Comment: This is an image, not a background image.

Comment: What do we achieve by having two same classes? Doesn't the second overwrite the first??

Answer (score 10):

You can resize images using CSS just fine if you're modifying an image tag:

```
<img src="example.png" style="width:2em; height:3em;" />
```

You cannot scale a background-image property using CSS2, although you can try the CSS3 property `background-size`.

What you can do, on the other hand, is to nest an image inside a span. See the answer to this question: [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 5):

CSS 3 introduces the [background-size property](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/), but support is not universal.

Having the browser resize the image is inefficient though, the large image still has to be downloaded. You should resize it server side (caching the result) and use that instead. It will use less bandwidth and work in more browsers.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
-ms-transform: scale(width,height); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(width,height); /* Safari */
transform: scale(width, height);
```

Example: image "grows" 1.3 times

```
-ms-transform: scale(1.3,1.3); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.3,1.3); /* Safari */
transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

defining this property in CSS was helpful for me.

```
 .img-small {
            width: 6rem;
        }
```