# Scaling background images with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, background-image

How does ones scale a background image with CSS? The image is attached with CSS, and I would like to scale it to fit a certain width

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: point taken. I did try to search, obviously not well enough ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try the following code:

```
.aboutpic {
width: 150px; /* replace 150px with something you need */ 
float: left;
background-image: url(../images/aboutpic.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%;
height: 139px; /* replace 139 px with something you need */
}
```

Then in the html just put:

```
<div class="aboutpic"></div>
```

It works. I tested it.

Answer (score 6):

With the [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property (which has [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a good way to start, "jquery.backstretch.js" is a very good jquery lib to scaling the background img.

Or, if your target client is using modern browser which means it can support CSS3,
use this:

```
body{
background:url(background.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp