# Css background problem

Tags: css

Hi yesterday I started creating a website usingonly HTML CSS and Photoshop.I decided to use as backgroound an image that   I found over the internet but I dont realy know what size should I make the Image so that it will look the same on any resoluztion.

Any suggestions?

This is the image I am using

http://www.google.ro/imgres?q=underwater&hl=ro&biw=1366&bih=667&gbv=2&tbm=isch&tbnid=dnNKiqNL0-pNWM:&imgrefurl=http://www.wallpaperweb.org/wallpaper/nature/underwater_8323.htm&docid=KWgRgTNbop2oLM&w=1280&h=1024&ei=H5NnTqTTD-jQ4QTkhYHVDA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=642&vpy=286&dur=1390&hovh=201&hovw=251&tx=111&ty=108&page=15&tbnh=155&tbnw=194&start=220&ndsp=15&ved=1t:429,r:12,s:220

Comment: Could you post an example of what your image looks like? That decision would be based entirely off of that.

Comment: Are you referring to the `body` background?

Comment: You *could* use media queries and target multiple screen resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to make the image look exactly the same at every resolution.  However, if you simply want to scale it to fill the page, though, you could take a look at this SO [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background/388817#388817).

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bit tough to tell but you might get away with using a jQuery plugin such as [backstretch](http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/)

Answer (score 0):

That image can't be set to be shown the same in all resolutions. You'll need to find one which has a gradient which changes to one color. Then you can set your background color to be the same as the ending color of the image.

Hope this helps.