# Stretching an image to fill a background using CSS background

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I like. I would like to use this SMALL image to fill my page but the image has a gradient effect so I cannot use repeat. Is there any way I can make it so the image is stretched to fill the page with CSS?

Comment: Duplicate of [Stretch and Scale CSS Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set the size of a background image. You'd either have to use repeat or strech the image itself with a a graphics editing program.

You could also use an workaround with an  `IMG` tag and CSS: [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background/388817#388817)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a rather old question, but seeing as I stumbled upon it, I might as well put an answer here.

It is possible to change the size of a `background-image` by using the `background-size` CSS property, like so:

```
.class {
   background-image: url(....);
   background-size:  100% 100%;
}
```

Take a look here for more: [CSS3 background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).