# Crop background-image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a background-image on the body tag which is around 500px high. This is fine for the index page, however on other pages it does not look right. I want to be able to crop the background-image on other pages to around 300px high, but still using the background-image in the body tag.

Is this possible using just CSS?

Comment: you can use custom css for index page only ?

Comment: I recommend you to check the previous discussion on this topic
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-size http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: This is scaling, not cropping.

Answer (score 5):

Make bg image 300px height, not crop, but scale:

```
background-size: auto 300px;
```

But you can't crop to an area smaller than the tag where background is set. You have to write a tag inside with the desired height set bagground there and then crop:

```
 background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like background-origin and background-clip could also help you