# Background always fills browser window, even on mobile browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, mobile-webkit, opera-mobile

I've tried the answers at [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background) (and also http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/) and it works beautifully in Firefox and Chrome, but both methods fail in the Android browser. Both techniques fail in the same way: when I scroll down the background stays behind, so I end up with a white background. (You can see the problem by viewing this page in the Android browser: http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php)

When I start scrolling there is an initial jump of the background; I think this is related to the location box not being visible any more (i.e. browser window size has increased).

The behaviour is basically the same when turning the phone from landscape to portrait; it is harder to see on the above example URL, as the background will just about fill the height in that example. When the text is longer it breaks in the same way.

Android version 2.2.1, built-in webkit browser.

The behaviour is different, but just as wrong, with opera mobile: as I scroll there is a half-second delay then the background jumps. But also the background only fills about 80% of the height, so there is a white block at top or bottom of the screen. (This is the "img on a lower z-index" solution; the css3 background-size solution does not work at all on opera mobile.)

Answer (score 0):

Did u try the media property in css.

Hers the link

[CSS3 Media Queries](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries)

You can use different CSS depending on the screen resolution

Comment: Thanks @Exor, that will answer the next question, but for the moment I simply don't know how to do the effect in android (or even if it is possible).