# 100% img div according to page

Tags: html, css, jsp

How can I stretch an image to use all the `WIDTH` of page?

I am using div tag.

```
<div align="center">
                <img class="s1" src="<%=image%>"/>
        </div>


img.s1
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
size: 100%;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img.s1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or .. if you want absolute positioning

```
img.s1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that the image be the width of its container, if that is the page, then so be it - but you need to specify `width`, not `size`:

```
width: 100%;
```

Similarly, you can also specify the `height`; this might become useful in your case, as, if you check the [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/f32GS/) provided by ShadowWizard then you'll notice, the aspect ratio [may be kept](http://jsfiddle.net/f32GS/1/) (which could either shrink the height within its container *or* expand it out of the container). Using `height` will [force it to size accordingly](http://jsfiddle.net/f32GS/2/), obviously.

Comment: +1, quick [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/f32GS/) (was going to post same answer :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the test case, prompted me to elaborate a little, too.