# Cross-Browser CSS solution for fixed, stretched to height background image

Tags: css, background, height, fixed, stretched

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stretch and Scale CSS Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

I am looking for a way to have a background with the following properties:
- be fixed
- stretch proportionally to window height
- cross-browser or at least solutions for all browsers.. (IE especially)

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find something to truly work..

Thank you.

Comment: The horse is long dead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reviving the horse? :D anyways, this can't be done by plain CSS.. or can it?

there's what they call `background-size:cover` in CSS3 (CSS3 is synonymous to "drop that old browser"). otherwise, i'd go for the JS solutions for the sake of older browsers.

[here's a demo in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) (not a good reference but at least it has a demo)

Comment: "reviving the horse? :D" Nope, still dead and beaten. Look at the duplicate, this property has already been covered in multiple answers (I count at least **five** in there, with [one added **this year**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9017171/106224)).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

- http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/
- http://ringvemedia.com/
- http://www.fiskebussen.se/