# HTML Background

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to make my webpage. I made a layout using Photoshop so effectively, it is a PNG file.

My question is - How do I integrate this into the website using HTML/CSS?
I tried editing the css which kind of worked.

```
body {
background-image:url('URLAddressHere');
}
```

However, when I enlarge the window, etc, etc... the image just gets ruined. 
Is there a way for the background to scale properly with page size? Also, I want it to stay uniform (i.e. it does not repeat)
Or am I just doing it wrong? How am I meant to implement this 'image' which essentially has my menu, etc.

Thanks

Comment: use a "div" to wrap background image and outside this "div" use a color or repeated image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    background-image:url('URLAddressHere');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a css3 property called background-size. This will resize the background depending on the width and height of the browser. I have linked a few resources below. You will also need to turn repeat off. Enjoy

http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

So for your class you may want to add:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: That will make things pretty ugly as soon as the image is enlarged.

Comment: > get higher res image. (worlds worst optimisation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want something like this....

```
html {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The question is about scaling the image correctly which is not reflected in your answer. Maybe you can update it?