# How to get background image/ image to stretch to fill container via CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image

I have a scale vector image and I want it to fill a container. There's a couple of these sort of questions on SO, although they are a tad old. E.g. [Stretch and scale CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376253/stretch-and-scale-css-background)

However, when I've attempted to implement such solutions the results have been disappointing.

For instance:

```
    body  {

    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000;
    background-color: #000
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;

}

...

.twoColLiqLtHdr #container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    text-align: left; 
    background-color: #003;
    background-image: url('background_image.svg'); 
    /*background-position: 80% 80%; */

  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Times", cursive;


    background-attachment:fixed;
    min-height:100%;
    /*top: 0;
    left: 0; */



}
```

I've tried various arrangements but I cannot make it stretch without leaving blank areas (repeating is a success of sorts, but looks horrible).

However, since I'm working with a svg am I approaching this in perhaps the wrong way, should I be using a svg xmlns tag in the html instead? (P.S. I'm aware of IE8's absolute inability to handle svgs)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you tried

```
background-size:cover;
```

Check some [examples](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/).

I had issues with webkit, `background-size:cover` and SVG background images. I solved it adding

```
-webkit-background-origin:border;
```

Comment: Thanks. cover successfully covers the container. However, and weirdly, the image is too 'zoomed in', such that only the top half of the image is visible. o.O As I have the image fixed it is not possible to see the rest of the image...

Comment: You don't need `background-attachment:fixed;` anymore, as it will cover the whole height!

Comment: It is baffling me a bit - but the background image seems to disappear entirely when it is no longer fixed! :p

Answer (score 12):

you probably need to add preserveAspectRatio="none" as an attribute of the outer `<svg>` element in the SVG image itself.

If you don't want to modify the image file then you could try

background-image: url('background_image.svg#svgView(preserveAspectRatio(none))');

Firefox 15 would support that and probably other UAs too.

Comment: Nice one, very useful. How can i use it with inline SVG encoded on base64, if it's possible?

Comment: I added the attribute to my SVG before converting to base64 and it worked like a charm. Thanks @RobertLongson!

Comment: Thanx a lot. You and preserveAspectRatio="none" saved my day. :)

Comment: Love you.
Love you, love you, love you, love you, love you, love you, love you, love you... <3