An unusual shape with rounded corners and a gradient border
I'm trying to create a block like this -

This block will contain content like text. It has unusual cutout on top, rounded corners, and gradient border. It should be responsive, width/height could change on smaller devices, when too much text and etc. Middle part of the block should stretch depending on height.
Here are more screenshots for better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://prnt.sc/-dCGHDm1FDBO
https://prnt.sc/xwY2YDKANRP0
https://prnt.sc/7FXGGKrTuFXo
just resized that shape in Figma as I needed and it works there, but in web it doesn't work like that.

I can't manage to do it, here's the codepen
Code from codepen:


.custom-border {
  background-color: rgba(217,217,217, .05);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 540px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.custom-border::before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: inherit;
    padding: 1px;
    transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    transition-duration: 250ms;
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    -webkit-mask: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff)) content-box, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff));
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
}

.custom-border-light::before {
    background: linear-gradient(156.15deg, rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.18) 5.68%, rgba(152, 152, 152, 0) 107.95%);
}

body {
  background-color: #201E2C;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  color: #fff;
}
<div class="custom-border custom-border-light">
  test
</div>
<div class="custom-border custom-border-light" style="height: 700px">
  test 2, more height
</div>
<div>
  <div>what I'm trying to do</div>
  <svg width="540" height="1329" viewBox="0 0 540 1329" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 18.5C0 8.55887 8.05888 0.5 18 0.5H132.085C136.266 0.5 140.316 1.95546 143.541 4.61652L196.957 48.6943C200.54 51.651 205.041 53.2682 209.686 53.2682H270H330.314C334.959 53.2682 339.46 51.651 343.043 48.6943L396.459 4.61652C399.684 1.95546 403.734 0.5 407.915 0.5H522C531.941 0.5 540 8.55887 540 18.5V1310.5C540 1320.44 531.941 1328.5 522 1328.5H18C8.05889 1328.5 0 1320.44 0 1310.5V18.5Z" fill="#D9D9D9" fill-opacity="0.05"/>
<path d="M539.5 18.5V1310.5C539.5 1320.16 531.665 1328 522 1328H18C8.33503 1328 0.5 1320.16 0.5 1310.5V18.5C0.5 8.83501 8.33502 1 18 1H132.085C136.15 1 140.088 2.41503 143.223 5.00217L196.639 49.08C200.312 52.1106 204.925 53.7682 209.686 53.7682H270H330.314C335.075 53.7682 339.688 52.1106 343.361 49.08L396.777 5.00217C399.912 2.41503 403.85 1 407.915 1H522C531.665 1 539.5 8.83502 539.5 18.5Z" stroke="url(#paint0_linear_718_1204)" stroke-opacity="0.18"/>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear_718_1204" x1="133.702" y1="-36.1539" x2="1109.56" y2="861.585" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#FEFEFE"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#989898" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
</div>



I've searched in Google but couldn't find a solution. Exporting this SVG shape from the design and setting it as a background won't work because the block's height can vary, and background image SVG won't stretch as I need. Also can't round the edges if I'll use clip-path.

SVG would certainly work I'd suggest IF you have the correct preserveAspectRatio set in the SVG.

Equally, clip-path does have curves IF you don't use polygon but instead use an actual path.

^ Exactly — see clip-path: path() and Understanding SVG Paths

@Paulie_DI , thanks for response, I tried setting different preserveAspectRatio, none of them worked as I needed, top or bottom of the shape are being cut-off, so it's not stretching properly. What I want is somehow to make only middle part stretch.

This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12601913/how-to-get-background-image-image-to-stretch-to-fill-container-via-css

tried using clip-path path(), but can't make it responsive, if the width will shrink - top right side of the shape (in screenshot) will cut off. Also this wonderful shape has gradient border, couldn't apply it together with clip-path... Idk if this is even possible.

I am curious ... why is it important to be able to produce this particular shape?

@Brett Donald , figma designer decided so

Does the shape have a fixed width or a flexible width?

@Brett Donald I need to make it be flexible width/height, for responsiveness on mobile devices. Basically make it act like normal div with "width: 540px; max-width: 100%", but with this unusual cutout on top of the block...

What should happen to the cutout when the width of the container changes? Should the width of the cutout grow in proportion to the total width? Should the angle of the cutout sides remain constant, or should the angle become flatter as the container gets wider?

@Brett Donald Just if it looks normal and not cut-off is enough. Here are screenshots for better understanding: 1) https://prnt.sc/-dCGHDm1FDBO 2) https://prnt.sc/xwY2YDKANRP0 3) https://prnt.sc/7FXGGKrTuFXo . I just resized that shape in Figma as I needed and it works there, but in web it doesn't work like that.

I think the most viable option here is to use properly "sliced" border-image, so it would remain responsive. I guess even the illustrative image in the question could be used for that here.

Using border-image -slice with provided SVG provides quite usable outcome I think:


html {
  color-scheme: dark;
  background-color: #161423;
}

div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-image-slice: 60 20 20 20 fill;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='540' height='1329' viewBox='0 0 540 1329' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 18.5C0 8.55887 8.05888 0.5 18 0.5H132.085C136.266 0.5 140.316 1.95546 143.541 4.61652L196.957 48.6943C200.54 51.651 205.041 53.2682 209.686 53.2682H270H330.314C334.959 53.2682 339.46 51.651 343.043 48.6943L396.459 4.61652C399.684 1.95546 403.734 0.5 407.915 0.5H522C531.941 0.5 540 8.55887 540 18.5V1310.5C540 1320.44 531.941 1328.5 522 1328.5H18C8.05889 1328.5 0 1320.44 0 1310.5V18.5Z' fill='%23D9D9D9' fill-opacity='0.05'/%3E%3Cpath d='M539.5 18.5V1310.5C539.5 1320.16 531.665 1328 522 1328H18C8.33503 1328 0.5 1320.16 0.5 1310.5V18.5C0.5 8.83501 8.33502 1 18 1H132.085C136.15 1 140.088 2.41503 143.223 5.00217L196.639 49.08C200.312 52.1106 204.925 53.7682 209.686 53.7682H270H330.314C335.075 53.7682 339.688 52.1106 343.361 49.08L396.777 5.00217C399.912 2.41503 403.85 1 407.915 1H522C531.665 1 539.5 8.83502 539.5 18.5Z' stroke='url%28%23paint0_linear_718_1204%29' stroke-opacity='0.18'/%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='paint0_linear_718_1204' x1='133.702' y1='-36.1539' x2='1109.56' y2='861.585' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop stop-color='%23FEFEFE'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23989898' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
<div style="width: 300px; resize: both; overflow: hidden;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
</div>



(Warning: I didn't try much to tweak the values and basically just tossed first what looked good-enough here. I guess with some calc tweaks and/or percentages it could be way better and perhaps even nicer in narrow variant.)


Some distortions of diagonals become noticeable only when squeezed to very narrow width:


Or with non-scaling ridge (but with resulting min-width constraint):


html {
  color-scheme: dark;
  background-color: #161423;
}

span {
  margin-inline: -200px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 60px 210px 20px 210px;
  border-image-slice: 60 210 20 210 fill;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='540' height='1329' viewBox='0 0 540 1329' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 18.5C0 8.55887 8.05888 0.5 18 0.5H132.085C136.266 0.5 140.316 1.95546 143.541 4.61652L196.957 48.6943C200.54 51.651 205.041 53.2682 209.686 53.2682H270H330.314C334.959 53.2682 339.46 51.651 343.043 48.6943L396.459 4.61652C399.684 1.95546 403.734 0.5 407.915 0.5H522C531.941 0.5 540 8.55887 540 18.5V1310.5C540 1320.44 531.941 1328.5 522 1328.5H18C8.05889 1328.5 0 1320.44 0 1310.5V18.5Z' fill='%23D9D9D9' fill-opacity='0.05'/%3E%3Cpath d='M539.5 18.5V1310.5C539.5 1320.16 531.665 1328 522 1328H18C8.33503 1328 0.5 1320.16 0.5 1310.5V18.5C0.5 8.83501 8.33502 1 18 1H132.085C136.15 1 140.088 2.41503 143.223 5.00217L196.639 49.08C200.312 52.1106 204.925 53.7682 209.686 53.7682H270H330.314C335.075 53.7682 339.688 52.1106 343.361 49.08L396.777 5.00217C399.912 2.41503 403.85 1 407.915 1H522C531.665 1 539.5 8.83502 539.5 18.5Z' stroke='url%28%23paint0_linear_718_1204%29' stroke-opacity='0.18'/%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='paint0_linear_718_1204' x1='133.702' y1='-36.1539' x2='1109.56' y2='861.585' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cstop stop-color='%23FEFEFE'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23989898' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
<section style="width: 460px; min-width: 420px; height: 130px; overflow: hidden; resize: both; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; inset: 0;">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</span>
  </div>
</section>



